# How to fetch user work experience from Facebook and display it as a list in UITextView

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook

How do I grab data from facebook to display as a list in UITextView?

I've tried grabbing gender and name from facebook but have no success with age and work experience.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
// fetches additional user profile like age and gender
    func fetchProfile() {
        let parameters = ["fields": "gender"]
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            if let gender = result["gender"] as? String {
                self.usrGender.text = gender
            }

        }

        let params = ["fields": "description"]
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "work-experience-id", parameters: params).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
            if error != nil {

                print (error)
                return
            }

            if let work = result["description"] as? String {

                print(work)
            }
        }
    }
```

It the results I've obtained from the log for 'work experiences' were as follows:

```
Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: work-experience-id, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=803, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 803;
            "fbtrace_id" = BO6mfzy68oj;
            message = "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: work-experience-id";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 404;
}}
```